# Bound on Expectation of a convex function of a Random variable

Tags: probability-theory, convex-analysis

My friend asked me the following question, which I at first thought was simple and straightforward:

If $X$ is an integrable random variable and $g$ is a convex function(all real valued), then is it true that $\forall a>0$
$$E[g(X)] < \infty \Rightarrow E[g(aX)] < \infty \quad?$$

**Question:**

My guess is that this would be true although when I tried to prove it, I got stuck. Let me describe my attempt:

$$E[g(aX)] = \int_{u \in \mathbb{R}}g(au)dF_X(u)$$

Put $au=t$, then you get
$$\frac{1}{a}\int_{t \in \mathbb{R}}g(t)dF_X(t/a)$$

If the $dF_X(t/a)$ was $dF_X(t)$, I'd be done. But I'm probably a step away. Additionally I have not used convexity anywhere so it's probably superfluous. I'd appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this matter. Kindly request clarifications if necessary.

Comment: Convexity if crucial. Imagine an unbounded function positive function $g$ such that $\int_K g = \infty$ for some compact interval $K$ and $\int_{K^c} g <\infty$. Now, take a random variable $X$ which has a support off $K$ - then clearly $Eg(X)<\infty$. However, if you take $a$ big enough, the support of $aX$ will contain $K$, so that expectation may become infinite. However, since $g$ is convex, it is continuous over any compact interval and thus such case is eliminated.

Comment: Good idea. Ill work on a counter in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Counter-example**: suppose that $X$ has [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Characterization) with $E[X]=1$, i.e.
$F_X(x)=0$ when $x\le 0$ and $F_X(x)=1-e^{-x}$ when $x>0$. Then
$$E[g(X)]=\int_0^{+\infty}g(x)e^{-x}dx.$$ 
For $g(x)=e^{\frac{x}{2}}$, $g$ is convex, $E[g(X)]=2$ is finite, but when $a\ge 2$, $E[g(aX)]=+\infty$.

Comment: Perfect. I wish I had thought of that. Thanks.

Comment: @GautamShenoy: You are welcome!